# ClientDetailTemplateId - when RTL (right-to-left) open icon is heading the wrong direction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, grid, right-to-left

I have built a grid which uses ClientDetailTemplateId to display details per order row.

I am also using the RTL style to display the grid aligned to RTL languages.

Yet the icon to open the details for each row is still displayed to the LTR direction.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is a working (or not working) sample code

Thanks

```
<div class="k-rtl">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-18 col-md-12">

                <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="rowTemplate">
                    <div class="orderRow">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                #:OrderID#
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                #:Freight#
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                #:OrderDate#
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                #:ShipName#
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                #:ShipCity#
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </script>

                <script>
                    var rowTemplate = kendo.template($('#rowTemplate').html());
                </script>

                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<APDashboard.Models.OrderViewModel>()
                .Name("grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).Title("מספר ספינה");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Title("תאריך הזמנה").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ShipName).Title("שם משלוח");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ShipCity).Title("עיר משלוח");
                })
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Filterable()
                .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
                )
                .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
                )

                @(Html.Kendo().ContextMenu()
                .Name("menu")
                .Target("#grid")
                .Filter(".orderRow")
                .Orientation(ContextMenuOrientation.Horizontal)
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    items.Add()
                         .Text("Forward");
                })
                )
            </div>
        </div>

        <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<APDashboard.Models.OrderViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=OrderID#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Title("מספר הזמנה").Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Title("ארץ משלוח").Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress).Title("כתובת משלוח").ClientTemplate("\\#= ShipAddress \\#").Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Title("שם משלוח").Width(300);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=OrderID#" }))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
            )
        </script>
        <script>
            function dataBound() {
                this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging using the debug tools of the browser combined with google search I found I can edit the style like this

```
.k-i-expand:before{
    content: "\e007"
}
.k-i-collapse:before{
    content: "\e002"
}
```

This gives me what I need plus there are many other icons I can place there.

Nice.